# Pull email + sent list in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk

Is it possible via API to pull the form of an already sent email & the list of people it was sent to?

I've been working with fuelSDK. I'm able to list out the sends but the recipient list is eluding me.
Basically I need to export 3 years worth of emails + recipients for a compliance issue which is going to take forever if I have to pull each send list by hand.

Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
        $rr = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
    $rr->ObjectType = "ListSend"; 
    $rr->Properties =  array();
        $rr->Properties[] = "ID";
        $rr->Properties[] = "NumberSent";
        $rr->Properties[] = "List";


    $sfp= new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
    $sfp->Value =  array("5");
    $sfp->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::greaterThan;
    $sfp->Property="NumberSent";

    $rr->Filter = new SoapVar($sfp, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
    $rr->Options = NULL;
    $rrm = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg();
    $rrm->RetrieveRequest = $rr;
    $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm);
```

This is the result:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (2) {
  ["OverallStatus"]=>
  string(85) "Error: The Request Property(s) List do not match with the fields of ListSend retrieve"
  ["RequestID"]=>
  string(36) "361bdc2d-dd49-4723-9e42-3161117970d1"
}
```

Despite the fact that [https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsend/][1]

[1]: https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsend/ says that "List" is in fact a property of the ListSend object.

My ideal return would basically be the "PreviewURL" and the array of recipients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3 years worth of data, I'd suggest creating a [Tracking Extract](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/) of `Sent` data.   You might have to do multiple extracts with smaller date ranges, if you've got a large subscriber base.

You can do that via API also, which doesn't create a visible Tracking Extract in the account.  Here's a sample SOAP envelope so you can see the structure of the call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Extract</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:ecb300c9-4131-44f2-834c-9e50dc4b1d86</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-07-14T13:47:07.429Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-07-14T13:52:07.429Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-bd7b0034-a8d7-43c3-8dfc-b2e84ae2e39a-3">
            <o:Username>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Username>
            <o:Password>
               <!-- Removed-->
            </o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ExtractRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Requests>
            <Client>
               <ClientID>CLIENT MID GOES HERE</ClientID>
            </Client>
            <ID>GUID</ID>
            <Parameters>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>Format</Name>
                  <Value>tab</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>QuoteText</Name>
                  <Value>false</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ColumnDelimiter</Name>
                  <Value>[tab]</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>OutputFileName</Name>
                  <Value>NAME_OF_TRACKING_EXTRACT.zip</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>NotificationEmail</Name>
                  <Value>aspriggs@degdigital.com</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>StartDate</Name>
                  <Value>7/12/2015 12:00:00 AM</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>EndDate</Name>
                  <Value>7/14/2015 8:47:07 AM</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeTestSends</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeMilliseconds</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractSpamComplaints</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractBounces</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractClicks</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeUniqueClicks</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeUniqueForURLClicks</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractConversions</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractOpens</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractSendJobs</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractSent</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractSurveyResponses</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeUniqueOpens</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>ExtractUnsubs</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
               <Parameter>
                  <Name>IncludeUnsubReason</Name>
                  <Value>true</Value>
               </Parameter>
            </Parameters>
         </Requests>
      </ExtractRequestMsg>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Do activities like a Tracking Extract require a specific license?

Comment: I don't think it's a paid feature.  You may just have to have SFMC Support enable it via special business rule.

Comment: Hi @adam-spriggs,
Maybe you can help me out just a little more. 
For background, I'm using PHP.
Same problem- I'm trying to do "ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest" on a "ListSend" via API. According to [https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/listsend/]the list is one of the properties of this object, but when I try to use it I get: 'string(85) "Error: The Request Property(s) List do not match with the fields of ListSend retrieve"'
I'll paste the code I'm currently trying to use in my original post.

Comment: Don't do a RetrieveRequest. You'll only get a 2500 rows at a time doing it that way.  Do a Tracking Extract and dump out a file.

Comment: A tracking extract on the Send object?
I'm having the same difficulty calling the list using that setup- the Retrieve is just the latest attempt.
Basically, I can call everything about the send I want, but can't refer to the list of recipients.

Comment: Yes, it's called `ExtractSent`  example SOAP request above.  It will give you all of tracking data for the date range you specify.

Comment: I hate admitting this, but I'm a bit of a novice at API/Soap in general. I really don't know how to use a SOAP envelope. 
My apologies.

Comment: I included the SOAP envelope just to demonstrate Object and Method structure.  Whatever you write in PHP should follow the SOAP structure.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% done yet but I'm going to mark this as answered. Thanks very much for your help. Once I forgot about the fact I have no idea how to work with SOAP queries and read the structure it made a lot of sense, so I think I have all of the pieces to my puzzle. It's probably going to end up being a Send extract, followed by a SentEvent extract and then pulled together in some way. Thanks!